# "I am trying to learn" vs "I try to learn"

Tags: grammar, tenses, progressive-aspect

What is the difference between present simple and present progressive when it comes to actions like the following?

> At school, I am trying to learn a wide array of subjects.
>
> At school, I try to learn a wide array of subjects.
>
> At school, I am studying Human Physiology.
>
> At school, I study Human Physiology

All the actions are not happening at the time of speaking. They all are somehow temporary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a subtle difference in meaning between the continuous and simple forms:

- At school, I am trying to learn a wide array of subjects.
- At school, I am studying Human Psychology.

These stress the ongoing nature of the attendance and the trying / studying: you are currently attending school where you are trying to learn many subjects / studying Psychology.

- At school, I try to learn a wide array of subjects.
- At school, I study Human Psychology.

These imply simply that when you are at school you try to learn many subjects / study Psychology. There is no special emphasis on the ongoing nature of these activities. They are reported as simple facts, analogous to other simple facts such as: *I ride my bike to school. I eat in the school playground.*

Answer (score 7):

The present tense is typically used to indicate habitual aspect, while the construction *be* + *-ing* form of the verb indicates progressive aspect, showing that an event occurs at the time of speaking or over a period of time before and after it.

That’s what’s going on in these examples. The first and third ones describe what you are doing over a period of time having the present at its centre. The second and fourth describe what you always do. In some contexts, they are interchangeable, depending on what aspects of the event the speaker wishes to emphasise. That in turn will depend on what has gone on previously in the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a native English speaker and never lived in a n English-speaking area but according to how I was taught, the present simple is more correct here, like in "I go to school" (every day) vs. "I am going to school" (now).

I also wonder if the comma after "at school" is needed.

Answer (score -2):

Among all the 4 sentences , below are the correct sentences.

At school, I try to learn a wide array of subjects.
At school, I study Human Physiology

Above sentences are simple present or daily works.so use simple present here

And According to my idea use +ing form for plans and events. example
I am going to attend the marriage.
I am going to finish this work by the end of the next month.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. The question asks "what's the difference between the two?" and your post doesn't answer the question.